# Replace subdomain from "www" to "app" via .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need help coming up with a RewriteRule that takes requests from the `www.` subdomain and translates them to `app.` requests.

I have tried something like this, but it did not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)www\.(.)$ $1app.$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond` for matching subdomain capturing value after `www.`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://app.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]
```